# How to count watson transaction usage?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

Alchemy API's transaction usage is returned under a response body property called `usage`. Alchemy API is being put to bed in favour of Watson NLU and its friends. While porting code from using Alchemy to Watson I noticed I do not see `usage` being returned in responses from Watson. Am I missing something or does anyone know how to count Watson transaction usage?

I've searched pretty hard in their docs and online but there doesn't seem to be any mention of this. I've also watched responses received by their Node SDK [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/lib/requestwrapper.js#L51) and could see no trace of usage in the response body or headers.
Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible in the API. For more detail, I previously answered this question here: [How can I get number of API transactions used by Watson NLU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003077/how-can-i-get-number-of-api-transactions-used-by-watson-nlu/43810429#43810429)

The short answer is that you'll need to calculate this yourself and then verify it on the Bluemix usage dashboard.

Comment: Update: I ended up writing something to fetch usage. Not optimal but works for me for a few projects I work on: https://github.com/coderigo/watson-nlu-usage